# Custom field update not committed with SQLAlchemy 2.0.20

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a problem updating the value of a field of a model representing an options table defined as follows:

**Option Model**:

```
from enum import Enum

from helpers.db import Base
from helpers.db.OptionValueField import OptionValueField 
from sqlalchemy import Column, String

from model.OptionsValue import OptionsValue


class DBOption(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'options'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    
    key = Column("key", String(50), primary_key=True)
    value:OptionsValue = Column("value", OptionValueField)
```

This is the model that represent the options table, which is composed of two string fields. The former is the option key that identifies it, while the latter is the associated value.

Since the value in string format can represent different types of data and I need to do some processing before loading it, I created a class that represents the readed value, while to load the data I created a custom column by extending the `TypeDecorator` class to do so that the model immediately loads the read value with the class created to handle it.

```
class OptionsValue():

    def __init__(self, value:str):
        self.__value:any= None
        self.__set_value(value, format)

    def __set_value(self, value:str):
       // the string field is transformed into a field according to the logic of the program
       self.__value = my_custom_Load_function(value)
```

```
from model.OptionsValue import OptionsValue
from sqlalchemy.types import Text, TypeDecorator


class OptionValueField(TypeDecorator):
    
    impl = Text
    cache_ok = True
    
    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        try:
            new_value = OptionsValue(value)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise TypeError(f"OptionValueField.process_result_value: {str(e)}.")
        return new_value.as_string
    
    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError("OptionValueField.process_result_value: Can only handle str values.")
        return OptionsValue(value)
```

I can correctly read and enter the options, but I have problems updating the value.

The key field I manage to update it correctly, in fact the following piece of code works correctly:

```
option:DBOption = db_session.query(DBOption)\
    .filter_by(key = "my_key")\
    .first()
option.key = "new_value"
db_session.commit()
```

If instead I try to update the value, the commit has no effect and the value on the database is not updated.
db_session.commit()

```
option:DBOption = db_session.query(DBOption)\
    .filter_by(key = "my_key")\
    .first()
option.value = DBOption("new_value")
db_session.commit()
```

- python version: **3.10.9**
- SQLAlchemy version: **2.0.20**